# Does anyone know why the QR Codes created by ZXing aren't valid?

Tags: zxing

I compiled ZXing under VC 2019, using the Cmake file included with the library. If I use ZXingWriter to create a QR code, like this:

```
ZXingWriter.exe QRCode "Hello, World!" qrcode.png
```

and then read it with ZXingReader, it says "No barcode found".

Displaying it on screen or printing it out and then scanning it with my phone doesn't do anything, which would seem to confirm this. (QR codes from other sources scan correctly.)

Finally, running it through https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx says "No barcode was found in this image. Either it did not contain a barcode, or did not contain one in a supported format, or the software was simply unable to find it."

I've attached a QR code I generated with ZXingWriter.exe: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/emr3N.png)

All the other code formats I've tried with ZXing have worked correctly... but it's QR that I need.

(I've tried the ZXing.lib library I compiled in the application I'm developing, with similar results - the QR codes thus created can't be read by anything.)

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

:Jack

Comment: I can't get anything to read that code, either - including a couple of QRcode debug tools that exist specifically for diagnosing unreadable codes!  Take a closer look at any warnings that might have been produced during your ZXing build process - something must have gone wrong during compilation for the program to be this broken.

Comment: Hello jasonharper - thanks for getting back to me.

I recompiled everything - not a warning to be seen. 

I agree - it seems like it must be something fairly serious.

If you think of anything else I might try, I'll be grateful.

:Jack

Comment: Consider adding one or two more relevant tags for visibility. Very few follows the zxing tag.